# Symfony3: set Custom FormType "name"/"blockPrefix"

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a `Formtype`. In this `Formtype` I get over the `options`-Array in the `buildForm` function a key `additionalName`. I want to add this value to the `FormType` Name (in Symfony3 BlockPrefix). But how can I set this?

```
class AdultType extends AbstractType
{    
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $additionalName = $options['additionalName'];

        $builder
            ->add('account', TextType::class,array(
                'label' => 'account',
                'required' => false,
            ))

        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Model\Adult',
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'name' => ""
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        //Here I need the $options['additionalName']
        return 'my_bundle_websitebundle_adult_'.$options['additionalName'];
    }
```

I tried allready to set a variable private `$additionalName;` on the top of the class, set it in the `buildForm` function and get access to it with `$this->additionalName` in the `getBlockPrefix` Function. But the value in `getBlockPrefix` is empty. SO I think the `getBlockPrefix` is called before the `buildForm`.

The Type is beeing called from another form:

```
$builder->add('adult', AdultType::class, array(
                        'additionalName' => $options['name']
                    ));
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the actual use case that you want to solve by dynamically changing the block prefix?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add a property to your FormType like that :

```
class AdultType extends AbstractType
{    
    protected $_additionalName;

    public function __construct($additionalName= ''){
        $this->_additionalName = $additionalName;
    }


    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $additionalName = $options['additionalName'];

        $builder
            ->add('account', TextType::class,array(
                'label' => 'account',
                'required' => false,
            ))

        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Model\Adult',
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'name' => ""
        ));
    }

    /*
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        //Here I need the $options['additionalName']
        return 'my_bundle_websitebundle_adult_'.$this->_additionalName;
    }
```

**EDIT :**

Arf.. I think it is only available for Symfony 2 before (2.8)..

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
class AdultType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $_additionalName;

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->_additionalName = $options['additionalName'];

        $builder
            ->add('account', TextType::class,array(
                'label' => 'account',
                'required' => false,
            ))

        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Model\Adult',
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'name' => ""
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        //Here I need the $options['additionalName']
        return 'my_bundle_websitebundle_adult_'.$this->_additionalName;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

getBlockPrefix isnt aware of $options['additionalName'], therefore you need a class property. And additional you can try with getName()

Comment: Doesn#t work, the variable "$this->_additionalName" is null when calling it in "getBlockPrefix".

Comment: I don't know if it works, but you can try to set the fully block name in $options array: $options['block_name'] = "my_bundle_websitebundle_adult__additional"

Comment: I think you can only set the block prefix hardcoded.